# DataTables filter input image change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I´m using the 1.10.22 version of dataTables.

I want to change the "X"-image of the filter input.

[image]

I can't find any background-image or anything else in the css file.
How does this work and where can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `x` is coming from input search field

```
/* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-clear,
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; 
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```